# Arquillian and JBoss EAP 7 embedded

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I've been trying different ways to run my EE 7 Webapp with Arquillian. To run it remotely or locally against a JBoss EAP 7 is not a problem but to run it embedded I run into all sorts of problems which stem from versioning issues, e.g. if I run it in JEAP7 all fine, in the embedded one I get an issue like I need to set a web.xml otherwise I have an AsyncDispatcher issue etc.

Therefore has anyone an advice on which version I can use with JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA to run it embedded/arquillian/chameleon e.g. to have no version delta in the embedded container?